# Background image size in div tag - Full screen - Inline css

Tags: html, css

I have been initially giving a try on adding background image inside a div. I face problem with adjusting width of image as per whole screen.

Referring to below, as per https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_full_page.asp , i tried to see if it works, But i don't find picture visible itself

[image]

When i add width and height , that too in pixels and not % , I am able to view the picture but the size doesn't fit screen perfect. 
[image]

Please favour on resolving this.

Comment: If the parent of that div has no height, a percentage on that div will have no effect because it's calculated based on it, also try to include a working example of the issue.

Comment: Can you reproduction the issue on jsfiddle.net with html and css? So we can look at it?

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the parent doesn't have a height, a percentage value on the children won't have an effect, because when you say `height:100%` that means 100% of the parent height.

```css
.parent {}

.kid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150');
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="kid"></div>
</div>
```

---

By default elements height is calculated based on it's content's height.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.parent').clientHeight)
```

```css
.kid {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="kid">kid</div>
</div>
```

---

In your case the parent has two children an `<h6>` and an empty div, since your `<h6>` has some text in it the paren't will equal to it's height, now we know that the parent has a height, so a percentage value on the children should work, but it doesn't, Why is that you may ask?

[The Specs says](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-height)

> If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'. A percentage height on the root element is relative to the initial containing block.

Basically if we say :

```
Parent
    height:200px;
Child
    height:50% // This should value to 100px;
```

However if we don't set it specifically it stays auto (means dependent on the content), therefor

```
Parent
    height:auto; which the default value
Child
    height:50%  // 50% of auto is 0
```

---

So you either set a height on that div.

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.kid {
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/300x100');
  ;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h1>losadf</h1>
  <div class="kid"></div>
</div>
```

---

Or on the parent, although it can cause some overflow.

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px
}

.kid {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/300x100');
  ;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h1>losadf</h1>
  <div class="kid"></div>
</div>
```

---

Or an `<img>` because it load the image and takes it's height and width, which i recommend since you just want to display an image, it's height can be perfected using max-height and max-width;

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h1>losadf</h1>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x100">
</div>
```

Comment: You opened my eyes!!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
background-size: 100% 100%; //instead  of background size cover
```

Comment: still the same... picture isn't visible

Comment: That's weird because it's working for me. Can you share code on plunker or something so that I can check it deeply what's the issue there?

Comment: And please let me know that is it a requirement to use it as background image? Otherwise there are several other ways to do what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Try using  float and you can adjust the width and height of your image